# Toggle animation in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want that when you click on the element photo the class tasklist fades in and out, I'm going to add more animations later that's why i want to use animate to animate it,
When I try to set toggle directly on photo and skip the bind it's only the photo element that disappears and not used as a trigger for the tasklist.

Does anybody know how to use toggle, in jquery mobile?

```
$('#photo').bind("toggle", function(){
    $(".taskslist").animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
},
function(){
    $(".taskslist").animate({
        opacity: 0
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On `vclick` use the animate function callback to create a new animation.

```
$('#photo').on("vclick", function() {
    var IO = this.io ^= 1; // Toggle state 1,0,1,0...
    $(".taskslist").animate({opacity: IO ? 0 : 1}); // or inverse  1 : 0
});
```

Comment: but when i click both animations are run, it's not waiting for a second click

Comment: @JosefCarlsson oh, sorry I missed that! Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

As per OP's request, here is the updated method that allows multiple animations. Toggle is based on the `opacity` of the target element. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwr2m/2/).

```
$('#photo').click(function () {
    var tasklist = $('.tasklist');
    var visibility = tasklist.css("opacity");
    if (visibility == 1) {
        tasklist.animate({opacity: 0, left: 50});
    } else {
        tasklist.animate({opacity: 1, left: 0});
    };
});
```

Here's a method using jQuery's `fadeToggle`. Take a look [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwr2m/1/) for a demo.

```
$('#photo').click(function () {
    $('.tasklist').fadeToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: yes, but if i want to add more animations that only the fade, like left:100;

Comment: I've created another fiddle to demonstrate the functionality you're after.